# How to connect a VB WinForm app to a SharePoint Database and extract its data?

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, oledb, adodb

I'm trying to build a WinForm app written in Visual Basic. It has a button which should connect to SharePoint Online and extract its data and show it in a DataGridView. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad topic so I will shoot some generalizations your way. From a 1000 yard view, I would use a Share Point Restful web service to retrieve your data. I would also suggest you check out the awesome tool called PostMan to help build write your code and test your calls. I don't think I could do it better than Microsoft so here are some links to help get you off in the right place. Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms458094(v%3Doffice.14)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms429658(v=office.14)